# How can I get multiple selectbox values in textbox in the order in which I selected

Tags: php, jquery, html

Now I get the values in my textbox but not in the right order. This is my code. Please help.

```
$("#Member_qualification").change(function() {
    var selMulti = [];
    $.each($("#Member_qualification option:selected"), function(){            
        selMulti.push($(this).text());
    });
    $("#Member_print").val(selMulti.join(","));
});
```

Comment: The `each()` should iterate in order the elements are found in the DOM. Can you show an example of the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `$.each($("#Member_qualification option:selected"), function(i, v){            
        selMulti.push(v);
});`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your question

> selectbox values in textbox in the order in which I selected

Makes confusion is it the order in which you are selected sequentially..?

`option1`then `option2`  even if `option2` is clicked first

if this was the case your code is absolutely correct and check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tintucraju/sr20dp3z/.

or based on the order in which you are clicked

`option3` then `option1` 
then

```
<select multiple id='Member_qualification'>
   <option>option1</option>
   <option>option2</option>
   <option>option3</option>
   <option>option4</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
var selMulti = [];
        $("#Member_qualification option").click(function(e) {
            if(!e.ctrlKey) selMulti = [];
            var thisOption = $(this).text();
            if(jQuery.inArray(thisOption, selMulti)==-1)
            selMulti.push(thisOption);
            else
                selMulti = jQuery.grep(selMulti, function(value) {
              return value != thisOption;
            });
             $("#Member_print").val(selMulti.join(","));
        });
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tintucraju/q5u1h7c5/

Anyway you need to select with `ctrl` key for multiple selection.

Comment: This is a partial solution, because one option is to select with control, but you can select multiple option using mouse drag so this solution doesn't cover the all scenarios.

Comment: Mosh Feu i have mentioned it in my answer `Anyway you need to select with ctrl key for multiple selection.`

Comment: @Tinti -  I saw you did. I just noted that this is not a complete solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  var selected = $(this).find(':selected').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();  
  });
  $('#result').html(selected.get().join(','));  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<hr />
<div id="result"></div>
```